# Parse Cloud Code CLI syntax using environment variables?

Tags: curl, parse-platform, command-line-interface

I am new to the Parse CLI (and not that comfortable with command line syntax to begin with). I copy pasted the following into my terminal (from the guide) to test my hello world function:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/functions/hello
```

This was giving me an error until I realized I had to paste in my own application ID and REST API key. That is quite a bit of syntax to just run a function!

I assumed that `${APPLICATION_ID}` would use the ID from my config files when I set up the folder. What exactly does this syntax mean (I've seen it used before in "environmental variables")? Is there a way to store these so I don't have to always piece together this long chunk of code to execute a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out. `${...}` is an environment variable. I had to add these variable to my ~/.profile file. I wrote:

```
APPLICATION_ID=XXX-MY-ID-HERE-XXX
REST_API_KEY=XXX-MY-REST-API-KEY-XXX
export APPLICATION_ID
export REST_API_KEY
```

Saved the file, then used `source ~/.profile` in my terminal. Then the code from the Parse guide works. Hope this helps other people.